# Inputenc package error on my new pc

Tags: errors, input-encodings

I have been having this issue for a while and I cannot seem to find a solution.

I had been working on my thesis on my old laptop for quite a while, but something happened and I had to get a new one and continue working there.
The problem is that when I try to compile the code on TexMaker I get the folloowing error:
 Package inputenc Error:

**Unicode character Μ (U+039C)
(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.**

The thing is that my thesis is written in greek, and there are a lot of accents and similar signs in the text.
Another weird thing is that the file was compiled in the previous laptop with no problems, and I only get this error on the new one.

I tried compiling example files in greek (which should work just fine) but I get the same error. I have been looking for a solution but none solves my problem.

I have already reinstalled TexMaker and MikTex, trying to solve the problem, but none of that worked.

Below you can see my main file, in which I declare the packages I use, and the text in the rest of the files is nothing special - its just written in greek.

Please help me because I am kind of panicking :P
Thanks a lot

Main Tex File:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twosided]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}

\begin{document}

\input{chapters/titlepage}

\chapter*{Ευχαριστίες}
Θέλω να ευχαριστήσω..

\chapter*{Περίληψη}
Στην παρούσα εργασία θα γίνει μελέτη των μελανών οπών {\en Kerr}. Αναλυτικότερα, θα μελετηθούν περιστρεφόμενες και χωρίς φορτίο μελανές οπές με αξονική συμμετρία ως προς τον άξονα περιστροφής τους. Αρχικά θα γίνει εισαγωγή της μετρικής {\en Kerr} η οποία περιγράφει τη γεωμετρία του κενού χωροχρόνου γύρω από μελανές οπές {\en Kerr} και θα υπολογισθούν οι συνιστώσες της αποδεικνύοντας πως αποτελεί λύση των πεδιακών εξισώσεων του {\en Einstein}. Στη συνέχεια θα γίνει μελέτη των ιδιοτήτων του ορίζοντα μιας μελανής οπής {\en Kerr} και τέλος θα εξετασθεί η ύπαρξη κλειστών γεωδαισιακών που σχετίζονται με τις μελανές οπές αυτές.

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Εισαγωγή - Οι πεδιακές εξισώσεις του {\en Einstein}}
\input{chapters/introduction}

\chapter{Chapter Two Title}
\input{chapters/chapter02}

\chapter{Chapter Three Title}
\input{chapters/chapter03}

\chapter{Chapter Four Title}
\input{chapters/chapter04}

\chapter{Conclusion}
\input{chapters/conclusion}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix Title}
\input{chapters/appendix}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't panic. Such message are normally easy to resolve.  Show the log-file of the compilation. (U+039C should be normally declared in your setup.)

Comment: I do not understand. What file would you like me to show you?

Comment: there should be a file with the extension `.log` in your folder (if you are on windows, the extension is perhaps hidden, then check the properties of all files whose extension you can't see). Open this file in texmaker and copy&paste its content.

Comment: Well i cannot find such a file. I can copy paste the log file from the Messages/Log window in TexMaker though

Comment: No search for the log-file. It must be somewhere (if you use a build directory it is perhaps in this one).

Comment: well I found the miktex log files. Is that what you need??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, is it a file with the same basename as your tex-file but with the extension log?

Comment: no. the only files that are like this are the ones with the extensions .aux .out .bak and .toc. I cant find any with the .log extension even in the hidden files..

Comment: excuse me my bad, I just found it!

Comment: Sort the folder from your tex-file by date and then make a screenshoot showing the newest 10 files.

Comment: I have the log file, how can I attach it?

Comment: you can either copy it in the question or put it one some web uploader like pastebin or whatever.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/VatrfZpu here is the log file

Comment: looks as if you found a bug in the miktex packaging. I need to check a few details and will be back soon.

Comment: Thank you very much! Keep in mind that this code ran perfectly on my last laptop. It is just on my new one that this problem showed up

Comment: I made a bug report https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/114. It should be repaired soon. Until  this happens you can get the missing lgrenc.dfu from ctan and copy in your folder https://ctan.org/tex-archive/language/greek/greek-inputenc

Comment: Thanks a ton! Could you please specify the folder in which I should copy the .dfu file in?

Comment: put it in the folder of your document and delete it when miktex updates the package.

Comment: Works like a charm! Can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @UlrikeFischer noted there is a file "lgrenc.dfu" missing from the greek-inputenc package, supposedly due to a bug.
As he said, Until the bug is repaired you can get the missing lgrenc.dfu from ctan and copy in the folder in which your tex file is.
ctan.org/tex-archive/language/greek/greek-inputenc

This apparently resolved my issue and it works great!

Comment: your solution works fine in the document `document1.tex`, but not in the `document2.tex`. How is it possible? I get these (https://pastebin.com/6jB7kk3q) errors.

Comment: I guess you should have the dfu file in the same folder as the tex document. are both of your documents in the same folder?

Comment: now it work fine. I don't know what happened... Ωραίο το latex, αλλά σου σπάει τα νεύρα ενίοτε...

Answer (score 0):

Package `polyglossia` will solve your problem entirely and it also has many more language friendly options which you can explore [here](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/polyglossia/polyglossia.pdf). I've removed many inaccessible commands from your MWE. **You'll have to compile the file using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX**

```
\documentclass[12pt,twosided]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Roboto} % Any Greek font of your choice
\newfontfamily{\en}{Doulos SIL} % Any English font of your choice
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Περίληψη}
Στην παρούσα εργασία θα γίνει μελέτη των μελανών οπών {\en Kerr}. Αναλυτικότερα, θα μελετηθούν περιστρεφόμενες και χωρίς φορτίο μελανές οπές με αξονική συμμετρία ως προς τον άξονα περιστροφής τους. Αρχικά θα γίνει εισαγωγή της μετρικής {\en Kerr} η οποία περιγράφει τη γεωμετρία του κενού χωροχρόνου γύρω από μελανές οπές {\en Kerr} και θα υπολογισθούν οι συνιστώσες της αποδεικνύοντας πως αποτελεί λύση των πεδιακών εξισώσεων του {\en Einstein}. Στη συνέχεια θα γίνει μελέτη των ιδιοτήτων του ορίζοντα μιας μελανής οπής {\en Kerr} και τέλος θα εξετασθεί η ύπαρξη κλειστών γεωδαισιακών που σχετίζονται με τις μελανές οπές αυτές.
\chapter{Εισαγωγή - Οι πεδιακές εξισώσεις του Einstein}
\chapter{Chapter Two Title}
\chapter{Chapter Three Title}
\chapter{Chapter Four Title}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\chapter{Appendix Title}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the main change here isn't so much polyglossia it is that you have switched to xetex and removed inputenc, so obviously the inputenc errors go

Comment: I still get some error messages regarding the fonts.
The font "Roboto: cannot be found.

Comment: @SteliosStefas You can download the font, or replace it with any Greek font of your choice. Whatever you use in your word processor should work, but one that comes with a matching Unicode math font is GFS Neohellenic.

Comment: This should also work in LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Davislor edited.