# problem with Greek after an update

Tags: greek, miktex-update

I 'm writing a book in Greek. The code is this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{kerkis}

\begin{document}
    Ελληνικό βιβλίο με ελληνικά γράμματα. Ελληνικό βιβλίο με ελληνικά γράμματα. Ελληνικό βιβλίο με ελληνικά γράμματα.
\end{document}
```

Everything was fine until yesterday.

- Yesterday I couldn't update MiKTeX or use new packages (e.g. `soul`), but I could compile and build my document.
- Before a few minutes I could update MiKTeX, but I couldn't compile or build my document.

[This](https://pastebin.com/ymwWRtrm) is the `log`-file. How can I fix it?

Comment: miktex is missing the lgrenc.dfu file. I already reported it: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/114, see also the comments here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501289/inputenc-package-error-on-my-new-pc

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for your answer! Should I do anything more or should I wait?